# JSON : Accessing (editing) value using dynamic key

Tags: json

I have a JSON Object which looks like :

```
{  "stepbystep": {    "steps": {   },    
                      "step1": "This is a step"     
                 }        
}
```

I need to edit the value of "step1" using a function.

My function is

```
function editJSON(parsedJSON,key)   // parsedJSON is the JSONObject,key = "stepbystep.step1"   
{
  parsedJSON[key] = "This is now step 1";
}
```

How do I access inner/deep values using dynamic keys ?

Answer (score 0):

Access your json like this :

```
// $js has json
 $response = json_decode($js,true);
 $stepbystep=$response["stepbystep"];

 foreach($stepbystep_arr AS $stepbystep_obj)
 {
    echo $stepbystep_obj['step1'];// here is your desired value
    //if you want dynamic step1, step2... you can use for loop
    //$n is count
    for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
    {
       $stepbystep_obj['step'.$i];
    }
 }
```